# How to check a page has busy cursor or not using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, automated-tests

I am not much familiar with javascript. I want a way how to check a page has busy cursor or not? so that I will perform actions based on it.

I am thinking of with the following code can I get?

var type = document.body.style.cursor;
does it work?

Comment: You should check the cursor style when the muse enters some element, You cannot directly get the cursor style from the window.

Comment: Actually i want to get what type of cursor that particular page has, can't i get?please provide solution.

Comment: You can get the cursor style of an element. But what ever you are asking is not possible. Tell me why are you trying to check the cursor style?? I can help you out with the right method to solve your issue

Comment: I want to perform automatic testing on page, if sometimes due to any updates if page has any busy cursor, my plan is to check busy cursor and waits performing actions up to when i get normal cursor.

Comment: OK the issue is with automatic testing, And I am not into testing, I would suggest you to edit your question add more details saying you want to do automatic testing and add all possible tags to the question. That way you grab more people attention into the question

Comment: Ok thank you for reply.